# is it better to store spatial timeseries data as a raster or array?

Tags: r, arrays, raster, spatial

This is a general question. I'm working with 11,000 days (~30yrs) of climate data measured over a 41x38-cell grid. For memory and speed, would it be more efficient to (a) store this as a 41x38 raster brick/stack with 11,000 layers OR (b) store it as a 41 x 38 x 11,000 array?